# Fix PCI/PCIe BAR address assignment on x86

Tags: linux-kernel, bios, pci

I read [who and when to assign PCI/PCIe device BARs base address?](https://stackoverflow.com/a/28295048/4688800) and [Bar asssignment in Linux](http://www.linux-mips.org/wiki/PCI_Subsystem). In second link the next was mentioned:

> On all IBM PC-compatible machines, BARs are assigned by the BIOS.
> Linux simply scans through the buses and records the BAR values. Some
> MIPS boards adopt similar approaches, where BARs are assigned by
> firmware. However, the quality of BAR assignment by firmware vary
> quite a bit. Some firmware simply assigns BARs to on-board PCI devices
> and ignore all add-on PCI cards. In that case, Linux cannot solely
> rely on the firmware's assignment.
>
> There is another issue of depending on the firmware assignment. You
> need to stick with the address range setup by the firmware. In other
> words, if the firmware assigns PCI memory space from 0x10000000 to
> 0x14000000, you cannot easily move it to a different address space
> somewhere else in Linux. There three ways to possibly fix this:
>
> . . .
>
> **The second way is to do a complete PCI resource assignment before
> Linux starts PCI bus scanning. In other words, we discard any PCI
> resource assignment done in firmware, if there is any, and do a new
> assignment by ourselves.** This approach gives us complete control over
> the address range and resource allocation. . . .

My firmware for x86 based system doesn't set appropriate BAR value which is works for me.

Is it possible to set BAR value in manual for x86 based system before Linux kernel starts? Maybe Linux kernel has some specific pci boot options?

P.S. No one of `pci=option` Linux kernel boot options helps me.

Comment: What does this mean? *doesn't set BAR correctly (address range overfill available physical memory)*  BAR values shouldn't be in the range of of physical memory, they can be above it.

Comment: @prl Or these days of systems with more than 4 GB memory, 32-bit BAR regions will be physically mapped below most of the system RAM.

Comment: @prl Thank you for the reply! I had a huge mistake about BAR value and ranges of available physical memory. I corrected it in the question. Is it possible to set specific BAR value on x86 based system?

Comment: ACPI provides for user-supplied DSDT information. Check with your firmware vendor how to do this.

Comment: @Ian, That's exactly why I wrote "can be" instead of "will be" above physical memory.

Comment: There are quirks in the Linux kernel that can be applied on early stages. If you really need one, you may write it.